# Windows 10 - High DPC Latency And ISR Causes Audio Drop Outs And Lag

Tags: windows-10, lag, latency

I've been facing audio stuttering, drop outs and performance lag on my Windows 10 laptop. The lag is sometimes so bad the Windows almost freezes. It lasts for around 5 - 10 seconds and then goes away for tens of minutes. This usually happens when the computer is doing heavy lifting like when I'm using Unity3D or watching a 1080p video on Youtube fullscreen continually for 10 or more minutes. This also happens sometimes when I'm playing a demanding game and I remove/connect the power charger. I've tried,

1. Updating all the drivers.
2. Disabling/Enabling hardware devices one by one to see if it helps.
3. Reinstalling windows from scratch and completely wiping the HDD.

These are the specifications [link](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c04334489):

1. HP Pavilion 15-p045tx Notebook PC
2. 2 GHz Intel Core i7-4510U with Intel HD Graphics 4400
3. 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3L SDRAM (1 x 8 GB)
4. NVIDIA GeForce 840M (2 GB DDR3 dedicated)
5. 1 TB 5400 rpm SATA
6. Windows 10 Pro x64

Here are 3 **LatencyMon** stats I took after an hour or so in between:
https://pastebin.com/yFHZtDNJ

https://pastebin.com/Lim22bwU

https://pastebin.com/UTivF7kT

Comment: Monitor temperatures for the processor and graphics if you can.

Comment: any good utility you can suggest? There are tons of those.

Comment: While the computer was doing some heavy stuff (backing up drivers, ~50% CPU usage), the CPU temps went up to 99 degrees and kept around 85 - 95. In idle state (while surfing the web), the temps are 58 - 70. How bad is this?

Comment: 100 degrees centigrade is max temp for that processor, so its very close to thermal shutdown at this point....

Comment: Would applying thermal paste and cleaning help or is there a hardware issue?

Comment: Usually just need a good cleaning using canned air....https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01657439